# Get Default JavaFx Window Icons

Tags: java, javafx, window, icons, stage

I want to add a title bar to my undecorated JavaFX Window and I display the default icons(close, minimize) to be displayed there.

My Stage contains A Border Pane with an HBox inside

```
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    HBox title = new HBox();
    Button close = new Button();
    Button min = new Button();
    title.getChildren().addAll(close, min);
    root.setTop(title);
    root.setBottom(grid);
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how do i get these default icons?

Comment: You can use [button.setGraphic()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) to set an image on the button.

Comment: but i want to use the default icons

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?